# How to force windows to appear when pressing Ctrl-Tab, even though app is agent

Tags: cocoa

I have a Cocoa application which I am running as an agent because it has a status bar component. When my application brings up a window, these windows don't appear in the list when I press Ctrl-Tab to cycle through applications.

Is there a way to force a window in my application to appear?

Answer (score 0):

Not while it's an agent, because it can never become the active application. Agents are meant to have only minimal user interaction, so it's assumed that you won't have an agent window around long enough for the user to need to command-tab away from it. (I personally find this annoying, because I'm constantly losing crash report windows behind application windows for the same reason, but it does make sense.)

However, the app doesn't have to be running as an agent in order for the status bar item to work, so I would just set the LSUIElement flag to NO and be done with it. It can be a regular, non-agent app that just happens to instantiate a status bar item.

If you don't want the application to be able to become active except when a window is visible, then that's more involved. You'd probably need to separate the application and the agent into separate processes, and have the agent launch the application in order to display the window. Then make sure the application quits when the window is closed, leaving just the agent running. Arq (http://www.haystacksoftware.com/arq/) is one example of an app/agent pair that works this way, with perhaps a clearer distinction between the agent and the app than you're after.